# Struts 2 + Dojo + Datetimepicker

Tags: struts2, dojo, datetimepicker

One quick question.

How can I use the "simple theme" () and "dojo datetimepicker" () together?

I have read that if you only want to use the simple theme, then manually import all the required dojo files using the code in head.ftl...

The thing is all those js are in struts dojo jar file which is included in the class path. How can I include them in the jsp? What should be the whole path? Any example will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **[Performance Tuning](http://struts.apache.org/2.1.8.1/docs/performance-tuning.html)**
>
> **1. Enable Freemarker template caching**
>
> In Struts versions prior to 2.0.10,
>   you had to copy the /template
>   directory from the Struts 2 jar in
>   your WEB_APP root to utilize
>   Freemarker's built in chaching
>   mechanism in order to achieve similar
>   results.
>
> The built in Freemarker caching
>   mechanism fails to properly cache
>   templates when they are retrieved from
>   the classpath. Copying them to the
>   WEB_APP root allows Freemarker to
>   cache them correctly. Freemarker looks
>   at the last modified time of the
>   template to determine if it needs to
>   reload the templates. Resources
>   retrieved from the classpath have no
>   last modified time, so Freemarker will
>   reload them on every request.
>
> **2. When overriding a theme**, copy all necessary templates to the theme
>   directory.
>
> There's a performance cost when a
>   template cannot be found in the
>   current directory. The reason for this
>   is that Struts 2 must check for a
>   template in the current theme first
>   before falling back to the parent
>   theme. In the future, this penalty
>   could be eliminated by implementing a
>   missing template cache in Struts 2.

---

**Example**

```
YourWebApp  
|-- WebContent  
    |-- templates
        |-- ajax
            |-- controlheader.ftl, datetimepicker.ftl, dojoRequire.js, head.ftl
        |-- simple
            |-- [All files]
        |-- xhtml
            |-- controlfooter.ftl, controlheader-core.ftl, controlheader.ftl, tooltip.ftl, validation.js
```

---

```
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.ui.templateDir" value="templates" />
    <constant name="struts.ui.theme" value="simple" />
</struts>
```

```
<%@ taglib prefix="sx" uri="/struts-dojo-tags" %>
<head>
    <sx:head />
</head>
<body>
    <sx:datetimepicker name="date" />
</body>
```

---

The **Datetimepicker** of Ajax Tags is bad, did you consider **[jQuery UI Timepicker/Datetimepicker](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/)**?

Comment: Thanks Ischin. Can you please share any example that how to include jQuery UI Timepicker/Datetimepicker in Struts2 project? If its good then definitely I will use it... Which jar file to include? Any taglib to include? Any change in web.xml? Thanks for help and cooperation. Regards. SC.

Comment: You mean something like **[Struts2 jQuery Plugin](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/)**? It is good, but I did not use it because I'm worried about compatibility of jQuery library (with other/third-party plugins). I just `use` the jQuery UI/other plugins in .jsp file. Maybe you can try integrate the `timepicker plugin` with `Struts2 jQuery Plugin`.

Comment: @SmoothCriminel The `jQuery UI Timepicker/Datetimepicker` has been integrated in `Struts2 jQuery Plugin` since version `3.1.0 (30 Jun)`