# Datepicker example in struts-2.3.16.3

Tags: jquery, struts2, freemarker

Here is my code, Struts 2 datepicker with time validation

```
<%@taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-jquery-tags" %>
<%@taglib prefix="s1" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<html>
<head>
<s:head/>
</head>
<body>
<s1:form action="datePickerAction">
<s:datepicker label="Select From" name="date1" displayFormat="MM-dd-yy"  />
<s:datepicker label="Select To" name="date2" displayFormat="MM-dd-yy"  />
<s:datepicker label="Select Other" name="date3" displayFormat="MM-dd-yy" />
<s:submit value="Click" align="center" />
</s1:form>
</body>
</html>
```

I am using this taglib

`<%@ taglib prefix="sx" uri="/struts-dojo-tags" %>`,

in body

```
 <s:datetimepicker label="Select From" name="date1" displayFormat="MM-dd-yy" />
```

finally my web page shows an error

> HTTP Status 500 - Error reading included file template/~~~ajax/controlheader-core.ftl - Class: freemarker.core.Include

Comment: What seems to be the problem prasad?  We can't help you unless you tell us. ;)

Comment: i am useing this tablib                                             <%@ taglib prefix="sx" uri="/struts-dojo-tags" %>, in body                     <s:datetimepicker label="Select From" name="date1" displayFormat="MM-dd-yy"  />                                       finally my web page shows an error   HTTP Status 500 - Error reading included file template/~~~ajax/controlheader-core.ftl - Class: freemarker.core.Include

Comment: @prasad Don't put code in comments use edit link to add a content. Also in you first code you point that you use `struts-jquery-tags` instead of `struts-dojo-tags`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `jsp` file use proper `taglibs`. Either use `struts-jquery-tags` or use `struts-dojo-tags`. Any one of them is enough for **datetimepicker**. Also use proper prefixes.

**For example** use prefix **s** --> `struts tags`. Use **sd** for `struts-dojo-tags` and use prefix `sj` for `struts-jquery-tags`.

```
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%>
<%@taglib uri="/struts-dojo-tags" prefix="sd" %>
<html>
<head>
   <sd:head/>
</head>
<body>
     <s:form action="datePickerAction">
         <sd:datetimepicker label="Select From" name="date1" displayFormat="MM-dd-yy"  />
         <sd:datetimepicker label="Select To" name="date2" displayFormat="MM-dd-yy"  />
         <sd:datetimepicker label="Select Other" name="date3" displayFormat="MM-dd-yy" />
         <s:submit value="Click" />
     </s:form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Don't forget to put `<sd:head/>` in head tag if using `struts-dojo-tags` as shown above. Similarly `<sj:head/>` if using `struts-jquery-tags`.

And for the issue of ftl file it is issue in `struts-2.3.16`. The [issue link](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-4145?jql=project%20%3D%20WW%20AND%20fixVersion%20%3D%20%222.3.16%22%20ORDER%20BY%20updated%20DESC%2C%20priority%20DESC%2C%20created%20ASC) . The issue is fixed and its status is closed.

**Solution:** Either patch provided in issue link or use different version of struts jars.

The rest of your question is duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114020/struts-2-dojo-datetimepicker)

Answer (score 0):

We were facing the same issue with struts 2.3.16.3 
The issue was resolved with struts 2.3.20 upgrade.